# VBA: How can I get around the slowness caused by publishing to a htm file?

Tags: vba, excel, email, range

I have some code that, when run, selects some cells, removes the conditional formatting on these cells but keeps the formatting, and then converts these cells to htm so that they can be sent in an email. The problem I have is that the process of publishing the sheet to a htm file is extremely slow and I have a lot of emails to go out, is there a way of getting around this slowness?

The code is as follows:

```
Sub EmailExtract()

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim Location As String
Dim PrimaryNumber As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim PrimaryRecipients As String
Dim SecondaryRecipients As String
Dim To_Name As String
Dim Region As String


Worksheets("Contacts").Activate
Range("A2").Select
While ActiveCell <> ""

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    PrimaryNumber = ActiveCell.Value
    To_Name = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
    If To_Name = "" Or To_Name = "0" Then
        To_Name = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
        If To_Name = "" Or To_Name = "0" Then
            MsgBox PrimaryNumber & " does not have a Manager with a first name."
            Exit Sub
        Else
            PrimaryRecipients = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value
            SecondaryRecipients = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value
        End If
    Else
        PrimaryRecipients = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
        SecondaryRecipients = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value & ";" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value
    End If


    Worksheets("Retailer Output 2").Activate
    Range("C2").Value = PrimaryNumber 



    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Retailer Output 2").Copy _
   after:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Retailer Output 2")
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Without Formatting"

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:M28").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Keep_Format

    With objMail
            .To = PrimaryRecipients
            .Cc = SecondaryRecipients
            .Subject = ""

            Dim Greeting As String
            If Time >= #12:00:00 PM# Then
                Greeting = "Afternoon"
            Else
                Greeting = "Morning"
            End If

            Dim LastMonth As String
            LastMonth = MonthName((Month(Date)) - 1)

            .HTMLBODY = "<font face=Arial><p>" & "Good " & Greeting & " " & To_Name & "," & "</p>"
            .HTMLBODY = .HTMLBODY + "<p>" & "Please find below your " & LastMonth & " Information." & "</p>"
            .HTMLBODY = .HTMLBODY + RangetoHTML(rng)
            .Send
    End With
    Worksheets("Contacts").Activate
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Without Formatting").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Wend


Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing

End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2013
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    rng.Copy Destination:=.Cells(1)
    .Cells(1).Select
    On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function

Function Keep_Format()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim mySel As Range, aCell As Range

'~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Without Formatting")
'~~> Change this to the relevant range
Set mySel = ws.Range("A1:M28")

For Each aCell In mySel
    With aCell
      .Font.FontStyle = .DisplayFormat.Font.FontStyle
      .Interior.Color = .DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
      .Font.Strikethrough = .DisplayFormat.Font.Strikethrough
    End With
Next aCell

mySel.FormatConditions.Delete

End Function
```

I believe (result from using the debugger) that the problem is with the following lines:

```
 With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: ADD `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` at the begining of your code, and at the end, set them to True. That should help you a little bit

Comment: Is this to go in the macro or in the function?

Comment: At the begining of the sub and at the end. Don't forget to re-open it !!! It prevens reloading datas on the screen

Comment: @Hearner I've tried that, it did help a bit but not much

Comment: If you want advice on how to improve *working* code then try the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site. Strictly speaking, SO is only for broken code.

Comment: Having said that, MS Office apps tend to write very verbose html which takes a while to compose & write to disk. One (long-winded) approach would be to write code that builds the html table by hand. It depends on how much formatting, etc you've got going on.

Comment: @ChipsLetten, thank you for your advice, I wasn't aware of the other site. There is a fair bit of formatting going on but the function `Function Keep_Format()` removes this conditional formatting. How would I do it manually?

Comment: Google "vba compose html" maybe? It gives [Roll Your Own HTML](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2011/09/20/roll-your-own-html-from-excel-vba/) as one of the answers. Be prepared to write a whole bunch of code...

Comment: I don't really want something that complicated. Maybe something like copying the cells necessary and then pasting them into the email as a picture? Would that work?

Comment: How many rows of data are we talking about? It may be a good idea to filter the data before you start your loop, then you would loop through visible cells only.

Comment: Almost a couple of hundred, an email has to go to each of them